# Add bookmark button to UITextField.rightView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield, uisearchbar

i have an UISearchBar with bookmark button on right. Like this:

[image]

Now, i have a UITextField with a text on leftView and a button on right view:

[image]

I created button on textField using default buttons

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd]
```

Is there a way to add in UITextField, on rightView, a bookmark button like the button in UISearchBar???

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is just to take a screenshot of the bookmark button, clean it up in gimp/photoshop if need be, and use it as the image in a custom UIButton

Edit: like this:   quite easy, just make the button and place it in interface builder on top of the text field

[image]

Comment: You can get a bar button item bookmarks (but without the colors I think), but stuffing a toolbar into a tiny space, that seems more hackish -- I'm serious, I think my answer is the best way.

Comment: i can't because the button is different (with color and size) and the toolbar is however too big to put in textview.. (is there also a border around button). thanks

Comment: You can make a button arbitrary size, including the size of the image.